# Deleted lines in review and revision-history bleed on to the other side

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, revision-history, diff

Where I observed the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15131865

[image: review-overflow]

My browser:  Chrome on macOS.

[edit]
Also happens on revision-history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5810383/revisions

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Firefox ESR 45.7.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Repro, latest Chrome on Windows 7. No repro on IE 11 on Windows 7.

Comment: Happens also on latest Chrome on Windows 10. Seems to be a problem with (the latest) Chrome.

Comment: I had to edit your title since at first, I thought you were talking about something else.

Comment: Repro, Vivaldi 1.6.689.40 on Windows 7

Comment: It should be noted that this happens only when you use the `markdown` view.

Comment: @Nisse the HTML view doesn't preserve white space

Comment: @TinyGiant: It does, in `<pre>` elements. But the two sides are scrollable in the HTML view, whereas they are fixed in the markdown view.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, because it isn't an inline element, you're correct.

Answer (score 4):

The following snippet shows that this issues seems to only be caused by one or more white space characters following the end an inline element's closing tag when the inline element's `white-space` CSS rule has been set to `pre-wrap`, and the amount of white space after the last character exceeds the length of the line box.

The [expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14724606/4639281) when this happens is that the white-space after the end of the line box should be condensed. Chrome(-ium) is—in this case—treating `white-space: pre-wrap` as `white-space: pre`.

The easiest work-around would be using the CSS rule `display: inline-block` for affected elements. Otherwise, you can remove the space, change the inner element to a non-inline element, or add a non-white-space character to the end of the line (also causing an extra line).

Somewhat relevant quotes:

> - pre-wrap Lines are broken at newlines in the source, at occurrences of "\A" in generated content, and **as necessary to fill line boxes.**
>
> <sub>https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space</sub>

> The width of a line box is determined by a containing block.
>   [...]
>   Since an inline box may not exceed the width of a line box, long inline boxes are split into several boxes and these boxes distributed across several line boxes.
>
> <sub>https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visuren.html#line-box</sub>

```css
.o {
  max-width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.o > * {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="o"><span>                     </span> </div>
<div class="o"><i>                     </i> </div>
<div class="o"><span>                     a</span> </div>
<div class="o"><span>                     a     </span> </div>
<div class="o"><span>                     a                     </span> </div>
<div class="o"><span>                     a                     ​</span> </div><!-- zero width space at the end -->
<div class="o"><span>a                     </span> </div>
<div class="o"><div>                     </div> </div>
<div class="o"> <span>                     </span></div>
<div class="o"><span>                     </span></div>
<div class="o"><span style="display: inline-block">                     </span> </div>
```

Comment: I've edited my post to report about a similar issue on revision-history.